# Will there be a difference between GGA and GGA+$U$ for material with Sc element involved?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, magnetism, dft-u

I have a material that contains the transition metal element Sc [3$d$1], and I want to know your opinions if there will be a difference between GGA and GGA+$U$ calculation. Knowing that the other elements in the material don't have d orbitals (just s and p).

Note: I  haven't yet performed the GGA+$U$ calculation due to the absence of the $U$ value in the literature.

Comment: Absolutely it can have an impact. It will also depend strongly on what property you're modeling. You should provide additional details about what you're looking to calculate.

Comment: I am looking for electronic properties ( DOS, bandstructure, ...) and magnetic properties.

Answer (score 2):

> Will there be a difference between GGA and GGA+ for material with Sc element involved?

- The answer is YES as @Andrew Rosen said.

> I haven't yet performed the GGA+ calculation due to the absence of the  value in the literature.

- You can take a look at [this paper and its supporting materials](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsami.8b14037) and find the $U$ value for Sc.

Comment: In general, 'U' values are not transferrable across different materials. For example, Scandium can have widely different 'U' values across two materials - say Scandium di-oxide and Scandium di-sulphide. It would be better if the original poster mentioned the actual material they are working on.

Comment: @Xivi76 Just a reference